# How to assign taxonomy field to user profile property?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, user-profile-property, visual-studio-2012

I want to assign a taxonomy field value to the user profile property which is fetched from ListItem. The taxonomy field is single selection valued.

The user profile property name is: `Dept`.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            string url = Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.DepartmentUrl]);
            string title = Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.DepartmentTitle]);
            string desc = Convert.ToString(item[FieldNames.DepartmentDescription]);

            //SPWeb newWeb = properties.Web.Webs.Add(url,title,desc,1033,Webs.Department.WebTempalate,false,false);

            List<string> nativeMembers = new List<string>();

            SPFieldUserValueCollection nMembers = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item["oiplbNativeMembers"];

            foreach (SPFieldUserValue field in nMembers)
            {
                SPUser user = field.User;
                nativeMembers.Add(user.LoginName);
            }


            var taxonomyField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Department) as TaxonomyField;
            if (taxonomyField.AllowMultipleValues)
            {

            }
            else
            {
              var fieldValue = item[taxonomyField.Title] as TaxonomyFieldValue;    
               var fieldValue = item[taxonomyField.Title] as TaxonomyFieldValue;
                SPServiceContext contex = SPServiceContext.GetContext(properties.Site);
                UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(contex);                
                UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(nativeMembers[0]);
                up["Dept"].Value = fieldValue.Label;
                up.Commit();
            }



        });
```

I am stuck by reaching the specific stage and don't know what do? I debugged the program and found that `var fieldvalue` is assigned taxonomy value successfully.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get TaxonomyFieldValue from the list. If it is multi-valued field, use this code to get each value

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tfvc = Item[taxonomyField.Title] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection; 
foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue e in tfvc)   {   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Label))    {     // e.Label;   }   }
```

[Here is my article which explains how to do various operations on user profile](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Manage-User-Profiles-using-SharePoint-Object-Model.aspx)

Comment: Thanks sir for replying, I tried your code but I am not getting the property changed, please see my changed code.

Comment: Just some thoughts. 1. First, check if the user exists or not? 2. Is it only problem with this field? 3. Did you try updating any other field? 4. If update doesn't works, try to add a new user through code and verify code is working fine. 5. Debug and see what is the value of up["Dept"].Value after the assignment.

Comment: Sir, I debugged the whole program and it is running without any error, and checked the user also exists.

Comment: Should I use the property name or the property Display Name?

Comment: Sir, I checked the property `LastName` of user is being changed but not the custom property.

Comment: Sorry sir, it was my mistake that I was checking other field name. Now its working.

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Great to know you made it!

Comment: Sir, I want to know one more thing that what should I do to append the value to the user profile property i.e. I want to append department value to the Dept property. For example, there is one value Department1 in user profile property and I want to add another department to Dept of user Department2 then Dept property should appear as Department1,Department2.

Comment: if ( !string.isNullOrEmpty(user.Dept.ToString()) 
{
 user["Dept"].Value += ",value2"
} // check this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11133/discussion-between-users1100-and-biju-joseph)